# Generate a compare link in bitbucket for a sub-directory

Tags: bitbucket-server

When generating the compare link using bitbucket, is there a way we can specify a path to the folder that should be showing up in the diff alone? It is kind of similar to the `git diff` command where it takes a path to the folder to consider for the diff (ignoring diffs from the other folders).

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked in the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.14.4/bitbucket-rest.html#idm46478325106688)?

Comment: @YuriG.the documentation corresponds to the REST API and not the HTML link on the webpage. I tried passing `srcPath` as an additional parameter, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: ok, it was not clear from the question. I think there is no way to do it